# iOS UIStackView .fill alignment inside UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a stack view that is programmatically inserted inside a scroll view (which is working perfectly) but when I put the scroll view inside the view controller in a storyboard the alignment is `.fill` and the distribution of the component is not applicable through UI. Then I coded it as below but it still didn't work.

Below is the code of programmatic implementation:

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController{
    
    private let dataSource = ["Student","Academic Staff","Non academic Staff"]

    @IBOutlet weak var userPicker: UIPickerView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstName: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var LastName: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    
    //message popping validator labels
    
    
   
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailAddressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    @IBOutlet var formStackView: UIStackView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        self.scrollView.addSubview(formStackView)
        
        self.formStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        
        self.formStackView.alignment = .fill
        self.formStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally        
        
        self.formStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor,constant: 20).isActive=true
        self.formStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor,constant: 20).isActive=true
        self.formStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor,constant: 50).isActive=true
        self.formStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
        
        //self.formStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive=true
        
        userPicker.delegate=self
        userPicker.dataSource=self
    }
}
```

```
I'm a very basic beginner in iOS; I need your dire help, thank you.
```

Comment: Try to clarify what you are doing. You show this line: `self.scrollView.addSubview(formStackView)` ... but you haven't shown where `formStackView` is coming from, or, if it is in another view controller as you show in your storyboard image, how you're loading it.

Comment: it is coming from the same, and it is functional and working, the problem is the stacke elements wouldnt distribute according to its parent element (the scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

That's an unusual way of designing in Storyboard... you *can* layout your stack view directly as a subview of your scroll view, and set up the constraints there (instead of via code).

But, I'll assume you have a reason for doing it that way, so...

You want to constrain the stack view's Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom constraints to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide** ... and then constrain its Width to the scroll view's **Frame Layout Guide**.

Try it like this:

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController {
    
    private let dataSource = ["Student","Academic Staff","Non academic Staff"]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userPicker: UIPickerView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstName: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var LastName: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    
    //message popping validator labels
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailAddressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    @IBOutlet var formStackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // not needed...
        //scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        
        // add form stack view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(formStackView)
        
        // because of the way this is designed in Storyboard,
        //  we need to set this to false
        formStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // stack view alignment .fill
        formStackView.alignment = .fill
        
        // stack view distribution should be .fill
        formStackView.distribution = .fill  // .fillProportionally

        // we want to constrain the stack view to the scroll view's Content Layout Guide
        let svCLG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            formStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            formStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            formStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.topAnchor, constant: 50),
            formStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.bottomAnchor),

            // constrain stack view Width to scroll view's Frame Layout Guide
            //  minus 40-pts, because we have 20-pts on each side
            formStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -40),

        ])
        
    }
}
```